# slow down foreach so i can display all GIFS

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to slow down foreach loop, so i can display gif which takes around 2 seconds to complete but foreach loop is very fast i cant see gif except the last one.

```
foreach (string s in words)
        {
            path = Dictionary.wordchecker(s);//Checks words for Animation
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\images\\" + path + ".gif");
            textBox1.Text = s;

        }
```

Comment: `Task.Delay()` perhaps?  Without more information we can't really know.

Comment: What are you using to display the GIFs?

Comment: Please show more code that highlights how you're displaying the images.

Comment: You should use a Timer, this way you can determine the interval. Also then you're not blocking the gui thread

Comment: "Slowing down the foreach loop" isn't really what you want here, as it will tie up your GUI thread and cause the app to hang.  What you really want is to set up a timer that will fire every so often, allowing you to switch which image is being displayed.

Comment: @HammadTahir http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40469076/edit

Comment: Also, you aoo is leaking resources by not disposing of the previous image

Answer (score 2):

As requested I updated the solution to work with windows forms,
You can do it like this assuming you have a list of strings for the words like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
List<string> words = new List<string>();

    int cur = 0;

    public static int Main()
    {
        //2000 is two seconds you can adjust to the amount you need
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Tick += timerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timerTick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (cur < words.Count)
        {
            path = Dictionary.wordchecker(words[cur]);//Checks words for Animation
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\images\\" + path + ".gif");
            textBox1.Text = s;
            cur++;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about when you get to the end of the list of strings? This will throw an exception after the first time through the list.

Comment: yep edited thanks,also in the original post I did forget to start the timer also it should work now :)

Comment: Yes, this should fix the issue, the OP could also do a "wrap-around" like I have in my answer if he wants to continuously loop through the images or he could just stop the timer if he only wants to display each of them once like you do here.

Comment: yep and since he didn't state if he is using Windows Forms or WPF or creating a UWP App I edited the post again to make note of this fact and the changes needed.

Comment: its a windows form application